# Dropdown Ipywidget not updating

Tags: python

I'm trying to code something very simple to update a Dropdown widget depending on the value of another widget dropdown value. I'd like the z dropdown to be the list of indexes of sublists containing the character c. Here is my code:

```
from ipywidgets import Dropdown

def index_us_in(char):
    l = [['a','b'],['a','c'],['b','c']]
    indexes = []
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if char in temp_list[i]:
            indexes.append(i)
    return indexes

z = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['None'],
    description='Sublists:',
    disabled=False,
)

c = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['None','a','b','c'],
    description='Character:',
    disabled=False,
)

def update_z(*args):
    if c.value=='None':
        z.options = ['None']
    else:
        z.options = index_us_in(c.value)
        
z.observe(update_z)

def display(c, z):
    True

interact(display,c=c, z=z);
```

Would you have any idea of why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it, I just should have called c.observe, not z.observe, my bad.